# Proving remittance from friend for a UK Visit Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am preparing to apply visa for my parents. My dad have income coming in from business but his account is usually low with balance which shouldn't be problem though.

But in may and june I have sent around 200,000 from my name and 300,000 from *my friends* name, after giving him them in cash. Now I am stuck with this stupid decision. That money shows like making his statement healthier otherwise his statement could be low however he does have documents to show his own regular income.

Anyways remittance is not crime and I have remittance reciepts but how can we prove that the money sent from my friend name was actually mine. We cant prove any relation with him obviously.

Comment: To be clear, is it genuinely remittance? Or will the money be returned to you and your friend?

Comment: yes it was genuine. the last remittance before these was in oct 2018 and then these big amounts in may and june. Does make sense it was after a huge gap and could be in bulk

Comment: Why did some of it come via your friend? You don’t need to tell us but you will need to explain in the visa application and it must be credible and backed by evidence.

Comment: How did you originally give your friend the money? You can provide, for example, a bank statement showing the transfer from you to your friend. And proof of where you got the money in the first place. Otherwise you might as well forget making the application IMHO - the UK is very keen on upholding its anti-money laundering stance.

Comment: Thats true. But should I submit any letter from him with his passport copy? or just explaining in cover letter would be helpful

Comment: Yes I am trying to be honest. Funds were paid into his account in cash. But question here is what if we dont tell them it was my money. and we can just say money from relative. Do you have to give any evidence from his name or prove any relation?

Comment: @Londoner Funds don’t just appear from nowhere - there is a source, even when the funds are in cash. You need to be able to prove the underlying transaction was legitimate. Doesn’t matter who it came from, it has to be explained.